# Choropleth maps for Germany

Tags: python, pandas, choropleth

I am having Revenue data which I need to map on the German map.

My data contains the postcodes, the corresponding latitude and longitude, as well as the value of revenue corresponding to that postcode, something like this -

```
data = {'35447': {50.6022608,8.861908900000001,434224.45€}}
```

I am using `plotly` Python library, which helps to create Choropleth/Point Maps. I referred to [Pandas Choropleth Maps](https://plot.ly/pandas/choropleth-maps/) example, which explains how to use `plotly`, but for USA. In the example by setting

```
locationmode = 'USA-states'
locations = 'AL'# AL for Alabama, AZ for Arizona
```

we could create Choropleth maps for USA. Similarly, by setting

```
locationmode = 'USA-states'
lon = -74.25908989999999 # Longitude
lat = 40.4773991 # Latitude
```

we could create Point Maps for USA.

**Question:** How can we use library `plotly` to create Choropleth/Point maps for Germany? Or is it that `plotly` is only implemented for USA. [pyGeoDb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyGeoDb) could have solved this problem, but it cannot be used for Python 3.+

As a side note, which may or may not be helpful - Choropleth maps [are not implemented for zip codes](https://community.plot.ly/t/choropleth-maps-by-zip-code/1408) and `plotly` confirms that.

Comment: This link should be of some help to solve this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948836/python-how-to-create-a-choropleth-map-out-of-a-shapefile-of-Canada

Comment: did you already solved this problem? I would need a map of new york

Comment: You can download German postal codes and their associated polygons here: https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads

Comment: Do you have the input data somewhere?

Comment: Which input data do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Well the fastest and simple solution to plot an interactive map with python is using bokeh. You can find more details in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-an-interactive-geographic-map-using-python-and-bokeh-12981ca0b567). The main idea is that you just need to find a geojson file of the country that you want plot and then the rest is pretty straightforward. You can find a geojson file for Germany (and many other countries) in this [github repo](https://github.com/isellsoap/deutschlandGeoJSON).

The geojson file basically contains the coordinates of the borders of the corresponding territories, so that the schema is drawn. Since you have the longitude and latitude of the territories that you want to show you can just check in which polygon (State, Regierungsbezierk, Landkreis or Kreisfreie Stadt) they are contained.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Guide on how to plot images from Canada which is explained here:

[Python: how to create a choropleth map out of a shapefile of Canada?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948836/python-how-to-create-a-choropleth-map-out-of-a-shapefile-of-Canada)

Afterwards, you need to replace the geo pandas shape file with German shapes. You can obtain these and add to geopandas as described here:

https://juanitorduz.github.io/germany_plots/